# Mocha test suite never ends when setInterval(...) running

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a suite of tests which contains code with a `setInterval(...)` call.

When running this code in mocha via a windows powershell command line, all tests will run, but the test runner will hang indefinitely afterwards.

The command I am using is `mocha "./unitTests/**/*.js"`

Is there a way to force the test runner to close?

Alternatively is there a way to determine that the code is running in a test environment so that I can disable my `setInterval(...)` calls?

Example code:

```
// MODULE TO TEST
setInterval(function(){
    // do cleanup task
}, 1000000);

function testFunction(){
    return "val";
}

export {
    testFunction
}

// TEST MODULE
describe("Test setInterval", function() {  
    it("should finish", function() {
        testFunction().should.be.equal("val");

        // This test will complete and all others, but the entire suite will not
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The root cause is that Mocha *by default* considers the suite to be "done" when Node considers that the process is "done". And *by default* Node waits for all uncleared timeouts and intervals to be "done" before calling the process "done". (An "uncleared" timeout or interval is one that has been created and never had `clearTimeout/clearInterval` called on it.)

A timeout is done when the callback you pass to `setTimeout` has finished executing, but an interval will never be done because by design it calls its callback forever and ever.

Your options are:

1. Determine a condition by which the interval should be cleared, and clear it with `clearInterval`.
2. Use [`unref`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref) on the return value of `setInterval`. This tells Node to ignore the interval when deciding whether the process is "done".
3. Invoke `mocha` with the `--exit` option (introduced in Mocha 4), which forcibly exits the process when Mocha is done with the test suite.

I would use options 1 or 2. The third option works but if your test suite becomes more complex, it could hide problems you should be taking care of. I would not use it if there is a more focused solution that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use done() to end the test just like this example:

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) done(err);
        else done();
    });
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: The issue is not that I am waiting on logic in the setInterval to complete (as "done" would solve). The issue is that the presence of a latent and unrelated "setInterval" call in the JS environment is preventing the program from exiting after all tests have completed.